# R - Efficient way to apply a match function on every element of vector

Tags: r, vector, match, sapply

I have a long numeric vector `x`. For every element i in that vector I'd like to know the index of the next subsequent element (in `x[(i+1):length(x)]` that is greater or equal than the current value in `x` plus a given number, and smaller than the current value `x` minus a given number, i.e. `x[i] <= 0.5` and `x[i] >= 0.5`. If no element in `x[(i+1):length(x)]` fulfills that criterion, the code should return `1e+06`.

I'm able to solve this with a loop, but this is rather slow. Thus, I thought about using a function and apply it on the vector `x`. I thought about using `sapply`, however, with the code below I didn't succeed. What's wrong? Which other way could you suggest to return a matrix with 2 rows or 2 columns for every entry in `x` that returns the indices?

Here is the code I tried:

```
x <- cumsum(rnorm(1000000))

fun <- function(x) {
  val     <- x[1]
  x       <- x[-1]
  hit.max <- which(x >= val + 0.5)
  hit.max <- ifelse(length(hit.max) > 0 , min(hit.max), 1e+06)
  hit.min <- which(x >= val - 0.5)
  hit.min <- ifelse(length(hit.min) > 0 , min(hit.min), 1e+06)
  return(c(hit.max, hit.min))
}

k <- sapply(x, fun)
```

---

As requested, here is an example. As mentioned above, I'm able to solve the task with a loop (that's what I've done below):

```
x <- c(5, 6, 3, 1, 4, 10, 9, 2, 7, 8)

res <- matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 2)
for (i in 1:10) {
  hit.max   <- which(x[(i + 1):length(x)] >= x[i] + 0.5)
  res[i, 1] <- ifelse(length(hit.max) > 0 , min(hit.max), length(x))
  hit.min   <- which(x[(i + 1):length(x)] <= x[i] - 0.5)
  res[i, 2] <- ifelse(length(hit.min) > 0 , min(hit.min), length(x))
}
```

The result would look like this:

```
res <- structure(c(1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 10L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 10L), dim = c(10L, 2L))
```

Comment: can you give some very short example vectors and what the return value should be?

Comment: Your text `x[i] <= 0.5 and x[i] >= 0.5` is going to only match the precise 0.5. I think the code is less confusing, but please edit your text so that the logic works.

Comment: @r2evans: Wonder whether it's better now. Tbh, I don't understand what you meant with "is going to only match the precise 0.5".

Comment: `x <= 0.5 & x >= 0.5` can only be true when `x == 0.5`, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: There is nothing that base R code can solve to make this problem significantly faster: whether a `for` loop or `sapply` or even a (slightly-contrived) rolling-window is going to have a level of inefficiency when dealing with larger data. Since your vector is large, I wonder if a quick cpp function would do better, so that as soon as it finds a value that meets your criteria, it can stop looking (which a vectorized solution will not do).

Comment: @r2evans: Ah, ok. But you know what I want to get? For every value in the vector I want to get the index of the next subsequent value that is >= x[i] + 0.5 and I want to get the index for the next number that's <= x[i] - 0.5. Will think about how to better phrase it.

Comment: I understand, and coming up with a naive vectorized (memory-explosion) or a naive non-vectorized `for` loop (slow) is not that hard in base R. But you want both fast and efficient, which I think is going to be very difficult without compiled code.

Comment: @r2evans: How would you've done it? I'd be still very interested in the memory-expensive solution. Thus, please share it. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Yes, in this case, for-loop is faster than sapply - because apply functions involve intermediate lists and lists are slower than vectors and matrices (because elements of vectors and matrices are of a single type - and thus neet not be that flexible).

Comment: since you have to check for each position anew till then end of the vector - simlple vectorization wouldn't do it.

Comment: may I ask for what you want to do this actually? what you want to do with those values afterwards? - perhaps there might be another way to do sth you think you have to do this way.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim: Sure. I have a time series (growth rates with varying conditions). After the condition has changed, I want to identify whether the time series' values either increase or decrease by a critical threshold. Therefore, my idea was to identify the first occurences for both directional change indications (indices) and then to compare the indices itself to understand whether a change in the condition led to a positive or negative change in the time series readings.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest compiled is likely the best way to go: ultimately, if you want to be somewhat efficient, then once you find one value that meets your condition it should stop looking (for that higher/lower condition).

Try this `cpp11` implementation. Note that I am no C++ guru, and while I think I've made this safely, please double-check it yourself. Constructive advice appreciated!

```r
cpp11::cpp_function(r'(
writable::integers_matrix<> next_index_diff(doubles xs, double lim) {
  int n = xs.size();
  writable::integers_matrix<> mat(n, 2);
  for (int i = 0; i < (n-1); i++) {
    mat(i,0) = n;
    mat(i,1) = n;
    if (xs[i] == NAN) continue;
    for (int j = (i+1); j < n; j++) {
      if (mat(i,1) == n && xs[j] <= (xs[i] - lim)) {
        mat(i,1) = j-i;
        if (mat(i,0) != n) break;
      }
      if (mat(i,0) == n && xs[j] >= (xs[i] + lim)) {
        mat(i,0) = j-i;
        if (mat(i,1) != n) break;
      }
    }
  }
  mat(n-1,0) = n;
  mat(n-1,1) = n;
  return mat;
})')
```

Demo in motion:

```r
next_index_diff(x, 0.5)
#       [,1] [,2]
#  [1,]    1    2
#  [2,]    4    1
#  [3,]    2    1
#  [4,]    1   10
#  [5,]    1    3
#  [6,]   10    1
#  [7,]   10    1
#  [8,]    1   10
#  [9,]    1   10
# [10,]   10   10
identical(next_index_diff(x, 0.5), res)
# [1] TRUE
```

And a demonstration at scale:

```r
set.seed(42)
x <- cumsum(rnorm(1000000))
head(x)
# [1] 1.3709584 0.8062603 1.1693887 1.8022513 2.2065196 2.1003951

system.time(res <- next_index_diff(x, 0.2))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   4.412   0.000   4.415 

head(res)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    3    1
# [2,]    1   37
# [3,]    1   35
# [4,]    1   19
# [5,]    2   17
# [6,]    1   16

system.time(res <- next_index_diff(x, 0.5))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   5.790   0.000   5.791 
head(res)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    4    1
# [2,]    2   37
# [3,]    1   36
# [4,]    3   34
# [5,]    2   18
# [6,]    1   17
```

The second batch is with `0.5` instead, and it's not really a surprise that changing from `0.2` to `0.5` would result in an increase in runtime (since it has to go further into the vector each time to find something outside of the limits).

---

<sub>*Thank you for the impetus: I've been intending to do some basic tests with `cpp11` for future projects, and this was a good small-bite to break the ice a little.*</sub>

Comment: This looks great! Now I just need to make it work myself ;). Thanks a lot!